# scrape odds using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to scrape this page, using Selenium in Python with Chrome driver

https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/england/premier-league-2018-2019/brighton-manchester-city/UFOgEYGu/

I am interested only on opening odds of Bet365.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0q3hT.png)

```
bet365_row = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='odds-content']").find_element_by_tag_name('tbody').find_element_by_xpath("//tr[@data-bid='16']")
odd1= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[@data-originid='1']").find_element_by_xpath("//td[@class='table-main__detail-odds table-main__detail-odds--first']").find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='table-main__detail-odds--hasarchive']").text
print(odd1)
```

I write this lines of the code, but i can scrape only the first odd of the table on 10Bet row, but wish the opening odd on bet365 row.

Comment: To get all the odd you have to add an 's' to element in `driver.find_element_by_xpath` in other words you'll get only the first occurence. try : `driver.find_elements_by_xpath(...)`

Comment: `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='odds-content']")
    bet365odd=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[@data-bid='16']").find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[@data-originid='1']").find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@class='table-main__detail-odds table-main__detail-odds--first']").find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='table-main__detail-odds--hasarchive']").text`

i write this, add find_elements, but i got this error:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_xpath'

Comment: Yes because `find_elements_by_xpath` return a list of selenium object. If it was me i would do something like this (look in my edited response)

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the rows in the table an then test wich row has bet365:

```
trs = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@id='odds-content']/div/div/table/tbody/*")


for tr in trs:
    if "bet365" in tr.text:
        print(tr.text)
        # Do whatever you want
```

Answer (score 0):

Perfect it works. I would refine by extracting opening odds

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqdQg.png)

```
 for tr in trs:
    if "bet365" in tr.text:
        odd = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('data-opening-odd').text()
        print(odd)
```

But i got this error 
  AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'